# GCE Firewall issue - Ports not opened after configuring firewall rules

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, whm, firewall-access

I am trialing the platform.  I have successfully configured and setup a CENTOS v6 VM and then added whm/cpanel. I am experiencing some issues with the Firewall that I am sure are on Google Cloud side of things.  I have read my eyes off and cannot seem to figure out what I am missing.  Please lend a hand.

I have an external static IP address associated with the instance. 104.155.x.x .
I can successfully SSH into the box with Putty. (SSH keys working a treat)\
I can successfully access port 80 and 443 using a web browser, however, I have added quite a few extra firewall rules and no traffic is passing to the instance.  The only ones that are passing are the 3 that were configured by default on setup when creating the VM instance, SSH, HTTP and HTTPS. I then confirm this using a port scanner.  Only 3 open ports as reported.

On the Console, I have created firewall rules on the defualt network, same place the ssh, http and https rules already existed.

(example) name: default-allow-2086 > source tag/Ip range 0.0.0.0/0 > allowed protocols tcp:2086

I have turned off the iptables service and can verify the firewall is not running on the VM.

I have a FQDN configured on CENTOS + whm/cPanel.

I have run both /scripts/configure_firewall_for_cpanel and /scripts/build_cpnat and verified the external IP was attached properly > 10.240.0.X => 104.155.X.X
info [build_cpnat] 10.240.0.X => 104.155.X.X

I have verified One to One NAT is enabled on this external IP to the Local IP.

networkInterfaces":[{"accessConfigs":[{"externalIp":"104.155.x.x","type":"ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"}]

I cannot find any indication that the ports I have entered into the firewall are open, therefore no connection to any additional ports outside of 22,80,443.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try to lose/remove the tags in your firewall rules as an initial step in your troubleshooting. Also, can you telnet to the ports in question (e.g $ telnet IP PORT) ?  To note, you need to have some kind of service running on those ports in order to connect. Just by opening the port, you will get connection refused if no service is listening on that specific port. Try nmap from outside ( e.g $ nmap -p port IP ) and netstat on the machine ($ netstat -tulnp | grep PORT) for additional steps.

Comment: Removing the bloody tags did the trick.  Thanks from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working. I have had issues with this in the past and now it is the first thing I check.

Comment: @JonBunch please consider providing the solution in the answer section and marking it as accepted to close this question off. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Web Console > Networks > Firewall rules, edit your RULE and remove TARGET TAGS and apply.

The